# How to use the textspan with dynamic data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here I am using textspan to show the list of items using map. For example If I have two items in list the output will be:

[image]

Because of converting to toList() so all the items are combined and looking like one paragraph.
Can any one suggest me how to use the map for my requirement.

Thanks.

code:

```
Widget _styledWidget(BuildContext context, List<CustomStyledText> styledText, AppTextStyle style,
    AppTextStyle styleBold, String semanticsText) {
  final scaleFactor = context.calculateScaleFactor(
    style.textStyle.fontSize,
    style.maximumFontSize,
    style.minimumScalingFactor,
  );

  return Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      style: style.textStyle,
      children: styledText.map((e) {
        return TextSpan(
          text: e.text,
          style: e.isBold
              ? styleBold.textStyle.copyWith(
                  letterSpacing: e.isNumeric ? PresentationConstants.numericLetterSpacing : null,
                )
              : style.textStyle.copyWith(
                  letterSpacing: e.isNumeric ? PresentationConstants.numericLetterSpacing : null,
                ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
    style: style.textStyle,
    textScaleFactor: scaleFactor,
    textAlign: style.textAlign,
    semanticsLabel: semanticsText,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution can be adding a blank line on the end of every `styledText` except the last one.

To achieve this you can append all the `styledText`s except the last one with

> \n

```
  styledText.map((e) {
    return TextSpan(
      text: styledText.indexOf(e) < (styledText.length - 1) ? 
             '${e.text}\n' :  e.text,
      style: e.isBold
          ? styleBold.textStyle.copyWith(
              letterSpacing: e.isNumeric ? 
           PresentationConstants.numericLetterSpacing : null,
            )
          : style.textStyle.copyWith(
              letterSpacing: e.isNumeric ? 
           PresentationConstants.numericLetterSpacing : null,
            ),
        );
      }).toList(),
```